# Highcharts bar chart with capacity

Tags: jquery, highcharts

So I have been looking through the docs to figure out how to do this but haven't really seen anything that would let me do exactly what I want. I would like to make a chart that looks like this:

[image]

The legend and bar chart I can figure out, my question deals with the capacity ratio. If the capacity is < 100% I would like it to show on the right with the actual percentage (as shown). If the capacity > 100% I would like the bar to be full and label/grid line to move accordingly some where in the middle. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have basically two options:

1) Use a dummy series.  You would add another series with a fill color of 'transparent' (or white, or whatever), and set the showInLegend and enableMouseTracking properties to false;  Set the data to the appropriate value to fill your empty space.

2) Use 'normal' stacking instead of percent, and set your data values to the calculated percent value instead of the raw data value.

{{edit ::

on re-reading your question, to accomplish the 2nd scenario, you would have to use option 2.

Instead of a gridline, use a plotLine set to a value of 100

- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.plotLines